# Simple database table design structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, many-to-many, create-table

I have a situation while database designing, A simple issue but needed a working suggestions

My database tables:

- TableAees.
- TableBees.

1. `Aees` can mapped/contain one or more records of table `Bees` or also can be without any `Bees`
2. `Aees` can also mapped with one or more records of table `Aees` itself

Here normal primary key and foreign key relationship/hierarchy won't solve the purpose and also worried that parent/child hierarchy may end up in forming a loop between tables and can give a duplicates records on various joins.

Need a better table mapping for above mentioned tables(a,b) which will satisfy 1 and 2 points.

So to avoid such a situation, how the table relationship/hierarchy will be a better approach?

Database used: SQL Server

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use a relation table?

Comment: Right now i am analyzing for better approach.

Comment: "Better" by which means? Please add some clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: No problem, i figured a working solution, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You seem to describe a many-to-many relationship. If so, you would create a thrid table to store that relationship, like so:

```
create table a (
    a_id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table b (
    b_id int primary key,
    ...
);

create table ab (
    a_id int references a(a_id),
    b_id int references b(b_id),
    primary key (a_id, b_id)
)
```

Each a/b tuple is stored on a separate row in bridge table `ab`.

Comment: Thanks mate for your suggestions.